# SVG as Data URI doesn't render (no <image> tag)

Tags: html, svg, data-uri

I have the following svg:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16"
    fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icon-tick"
    style="width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-top: 5px;">
    <path d="M2 9.66667L5.33333 13L14 3" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

It renders just fine in the browser. However, it wkhtmltopdf doesn't render it, so I thought I'd try changing it to a data URI instead. When I do that, however, the browser doesn't render it anymore:

```html
<img style="width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-top: 5px;" src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16"
    fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icon-tick"
    style="width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-top: 5px;">
    <path d="M2 9.66667L5.33333 13L14 3" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>' alt="" />
```

I'm using https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/ as a reference, which demonstrates that it isn't necessary to encode the special characters in the svg. I have tried encoding the special characters, and it doesn't make any difference.

Why doesn't the svg render?

Comment: It does render, but you haven't given the img enough height to fully render the svg. If you remove the img's css height/width you will see.

Comment: How so? That had occurred to me as a possibility, so I set the height on the <img> element to match the width and height on the <svg> (12px x 12px), which you can see in the <img> example. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: OK, hold on. I've been trying different versions of this for some time now, and I've never seen anything I did have an effect. I just refreshed the page for the 100th time, and I can see it now. I have no idea why it never displayed before. Thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It's working (Chrome/Win) if you remove the now-inappropriate `style` attribute from the SVG.

```html
<img style="width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-top: 5px;" src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16"
    fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icon-tick">
    <path d="M2 9.66667L5.33333 13L14 3" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>' alt="" />
```

Comment: and you can easliy slim it down to: ``data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 8 8" fill="transparent" stroke="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1 4.8L2.65 6.5L6 3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></svg>``